# Are spells gained from class abilities considered as in spell list?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spellcasting, domains

For the purposes of crafting, casting spells from scrolls and so forth,

**Are spells gained from cleric domains, oracle mysteries, wizard elemental schools, sorcerer bloodlines and other such class abilities considered to be on your spell list?**

Continuation for example questions:
Can you as a lower level cleric with destruction domain, who hasn't yet reached 7th level domain slot, cast disintegrate from a scroll obtained from a colleague who has written a divine scroll of disintegrate? Does this similarly apply to classes which get spells from other spellcasting classes, or are they different from domain spells?

Answer (score 5):

#### It's on a case by case basis.

- Spells from domains are only usable by default in their designated spell slot, and are not added to the spell list. They still can count for crafting or any prerequisite that says "able to cast X," provided the character is at a high enough level to be able to cast the required spell normally. However, they don't have access to items like scrolls that require the spell to be on their spell list.
- Spells from bloodlines and mysteries are directly added to the character's known spells. This allows them to be cast using regular spell slots, but it doesn't mention anything about adding them to the spell list. As a result, they probably aren't, so they have the same interactions with external systems as the domain spells.
- Extra spells from a wizard taking an exotic elemental school (the regular ones only include spells normally on the wizard list) are described as being added to the spell list. They have no restrictions compared to normal wizard spells.

Comment: [Pro tip about headers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/use-real-headers-instead-of-fake-headers)

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not.

> Each [domain](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Cleric/#Domains) grants a number of domain powers, dependent upon the level of the cleric, as well as a number of bonus spells. A cleric gains one domain spell slot for each level of cleric spell she can cast, from 1st on up. Each day, a cleric can prepare one of the spells from her two domains in that slot. *If a domain spell is not on the cleric spell list, a cleric can prepare it only in her domain spell slot.* Domain spells cannot be used to cast spells spontaneously.

If all domain spells were considered to be on your class spell list, then the italicized section would not have any effect, while instead it's rather crucial to the domain functionality.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Are spells gained from cleric domains, oracle mysteries, wizard elemental schools, sorcerer bloodlines and other such class abilities
> considered to be on your spell list?***

### Sometimes

First, unless an ability explicitly says that it does add a spell to your class' spell list, it doesn't.

Second, class features that add a spell to the Spells Known of a character, also add that spell to the class' spell list as well. [This is from a FAQ, see below]

Third, even if an ability adds a spell to a class' spell list, these spells are only added to the class' spell list once the character reaches the point of getting that bonus spell – unless the ability explicitly states otherwise.

Cleric Domains and Wizard Schools make it very clear that these spells can only be prepared in the Domain/School spell slot, not in the normal class spell slots (unless they are on the cleric/wizard spell list anyway). Normal class spell-slots can only be used to cast spells that appear on the spell list of that class.

As a result:

- Domain spells are *not* added to the (cleric's) spell list
- School spells are *not* added to the (wizard's) spell list
- Mystery spells are added to the (oracle's) spell list
- Bloodline spells are added to the (sorcerer's) spell list

But again, they are only added to the class' spell list when the character receives that bonus spell.

For example, a 3rd-level Sorcerer adds the 1st-level spell gained from his Bloodline to his Spells Known and the sorcerer spell list, but the bonus spells gained at the 5th sorcerer level or higher are not yet added to the sorcerer spell list.

As another example, a [Wood Wizard's school](https://www.aonprd.com/SchoolDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wood) explicitly states that it adds certain spells to the wizard spell list, and all of those spells are added immediately to the spell list, you do not have to wait to reach a certain level:

> ***Wood Magic:** At 1st level, add the following spells to your wizard spell list at the listed spell level: 2nd—entangle, 3rd—tree shape,
> 4th—plant growth, 5th—command plants, 6th—tree stride, 7th—liveoak,
> 8th—transmute metal to wood, 9th—control plants.*

---

[FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9s54):

> ***New Spells Known: If I gain the ability to add a spell that is not on my spell list to my list of spells known, without adding it to my
> spell list, can I cast it?***
>
> *No. Adding a spell to your list of spells known does not add it to the spell list of that class unless they are added by a class feature
> of that same class. For example, sorcerers add their bloodline spells
> to their sorcerer spell list and oracles add their mystery spells to
> their oracle spell list. The spell slots of a class can only be used
> to cast spells that appear on the spell list of that class.*

---

> ***For the purposes of crafting, casting spells from scrolls and so forth, …***

Make sure to read the specific item crafting rules carefully. For example, a Wizard can [craft scrolls](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Magic%20Item%20Creation&Category=Magic%20Items) of any spells he has prepared, regardless of whether they are on his spell list or not:

> The creator must have prepared the spell to be scribed (or must know
> the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard) and must provide any
> material component or focus the spell requires. A material component
> is consumed when she begins writing, but a focus is not. (A focus used
> in scribing a scroll can be reused.) The act of writing triggers the
> prepared spell, making it unavailable for casting until the character
> has rested and regained spells. (That is, that spell slot is expended
> from the caster’s currently prepared spells, just as if it had been
> cast.)

Thus, a Wizard or Cleric can scribe scrolls with the spells they have prepared in their School/Domain spell-slots, even if these spells are not on their class spell list.

---

> ***Can you as a lower level cleric with destruction domain, who hasn't yet reached 7th level domain slot, cast disintegrate from a scroll
> obtained from a colleague who has written a divine scroll of
> disintegrate?***

No, as explained above.